# Calling TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData() Method more than once

Tags: c#, wpf

I am seeing an odd behavior when trying to change time zone information from within a WPF app. I have an application that I change date time and/or time zone settings via Win32 API.

I notice that if I call TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData() after changing time zones the first time, everything works as expected and I can check TimeZoneInfo.Local and the time zone is updated to what I expect it to be, and the application is still responsive.

However, if I try to change the timezone again (changing it works, as I see it update on the system), and then call TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData() a second time, somehow the WPF navigation controls stop working - I have a back button that no longer works and buttons that take you to other views that are no longer working. It's like the command bindings just disappeared. Break points inside the command handlers no longer are hit. If I pause the app I do not see any threads that are hanging, CPU is normal.

I have tried calling TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData() on a ThreadPool thread, and I have tried running it on the Dispatcher thread, same result if called more than once during runtime.

As soon as I remove the attempt to clear the cache from the code, everything works as I want, as many times as I want, except of course that my TimeZoneInfo.Local is not updated, which is what I need.

I also do not have any references to TimeZoneInfo.Local hanging around when I change the time zone.

I would love it if someone could tell me why this is the case.

Comment: Having to call ClearCachedData explicitly (don't forget CultureInfo.ClearCachedData) was done to ensure that programs do not misbehave when the current time suddenly jumps by an hour or more.  They often have an indirect dependency on time steadily progressing and act badly when it doesn't.  Sounds familiar?